# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12

Tags: java

Before I append the record into the textfile, it's all ok, but when I append the record into textfile, it start to have error when i run the program. I now no idea where got wrong

**first error**

```
javaapplication1.LoginWindow.actionPerformed(LoginWindow.java:102)
```

belongs to this line of code `Dashboard d = new Dashboard();`

**second error**

```
javaapplication1.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:200)
```

belongs to this line of code `data[i][12] = "" +  std.getAcdmcq1();`

[Output Photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLtuJ.png) This picture show the output of record that I append to the textfile

Below are the error shown

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at javaapplication1.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:200)
    at javaapplication1.LoginWindow.actionPerformed(LoginWindow.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This is LoginWindow.java:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class LoginWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener,ItemListener,MouseListener{
    private JLabel userName_label;
    private JTextField userName;
    private JLabel password_label;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JButton loginButton;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JCheckBox display_pswrd;
    private JLabel noAccount;
    private JLabel role;
    private JComboBox roleCmb;
    
    
    public LoginWindow(){
        final int win_width = 300; //window width in pixels
        final int win_height = 250; //window height in pixels
        
        setTitle("Login"); //set this window's title
        setSize(win_width,win_height); //set the size of this window
        

        //Create the components here
        userName_label = new JLabel("Username: ");
        userName_label.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
        userName = new JTextField(15);
        userName.setBounds(100,20,165,25);
        password_label = new JLabel("Password: ");
        password_label.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
        password = new JPasswordField(15);
        password.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(80,140,80,25);
        loginButton.addActionListener(this); 
        role = new JLabel("Role: ");
        role.setBounds(10,80,80,25);
        String []roleList = {"","Admin","Lecturer"};
        roleCmb = new JComboBox(roleList);
        roleCmb.setBounds(100, 80, 165, 25);
        display_pswrd = new JCheckBox("Show password");
        display_pswrd.setBounds(100,110,165,25);
        display_pswrd.addItemListener(this);
        noAccount = new JLabel("Didn't have account ?");
        noAccount.setBounds(70,170,165,25);
        //set text color
        noAccount.setForeground(Color.BLUE); //set text color
        noAccount.addMouseListener(this);
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        //Set layout of the component which the component in the panel will align vertically
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(userName_label);
        panel.add(userName);
        panel.add(password_label);
        panel.add(password);
        panel.add(role);
        panel.add(roleCmb);
        panel.add(display_pswrd);
        panel.add(loginButton);
        panel.add(noAccount);
        
        //set border for the panel
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Panel is added to the JFrane's content panel
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        //Set this frame visible and display
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        
        if(e.getSource() == loginButton){           
            //boolean usrFound = false;
            String usr = userName.getText();
            String pswrd = password.getText();
            String loginRole = roleCmb.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for(User user :AcademicSystem.allUser){  //for each user with details of username, password and role
                if(user.getLogin_username().equals(usr)&&user.getLogin_password().equals(pswrd)&&user.getRole().equals(loginRole)){
                    AcademicSystem.user = user;
                    System.out.println(user.getLogin_username() + "\t" + userName.getText());
                    System.out.println(user.getLogin_password() + "\t"  + password.getText());
                    System.out.println(user.getRole() + "\t"  + roleCmb.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            
            if(AcademicSystem.user!=null){
                if(roleCmb.getSelectedItem()=="Admin"){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginButton,"Username and password matched!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginButton, "User[" + userName.getText() + "] have successfully logged in as " + roleCmb.getSelectedItem().toString() );
                    setVisible(false);
                    Dashboard d = new Dashboard();
                    d.setVisible(true);
                    //usrFound = true;
                }else if(roleCmb.getSelectedItem()=="Lecturer"){
                    LecturerMenu lm = new LecturerMenu();
                    setVisible(false);
                    lm.setVisible(true);
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginButton,"User not found");
                AcademicSystem.user = null;
            } 
            
            try{
                PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Logfile.txt", true)); //open the file in append mode
                //p.print("USERNAME\tROLE\t\tACTION\t\tLOGON_TIME\n");
                p.print(AcademicSystem.user.getLogin_username() + "\n");
                p.print(AcademicSystem.user.getRole()+ "\n");
                p.print("Login" + "\n");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:s");
                p.print(simpleformat.format(cal.getTime())+"\n");
                p.println();
                p.close();
                
            }catch(Exception er){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,er);
            }
            
            
        }  
    }
    
    //Detect the change of state of checkbox 
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        if (ie.getSource() == display_pswrd){
            if(display_pswrd.isSelected()){
                 // Setting a value of 0 indicates that you wish to see the text
                //as it is typed, similar to the behavior of a standard JTextField
                display_pswrd.setText("Hide Password");
                password.setEchoChar((char)0);
            }else{
                display_pswrd.setText("Show Password");
                password.setEchoChar('*');
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do your want to a register a new account?");
        
        if (a == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            setVisible(false);
            Register rg = new Register();
            rg.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        else{
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
     //...
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        //...
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        //....
    }
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        ///......
    }
}
```

This is my Dashboard.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class Dashboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //declaration here
    private JTabbedPane tp;
    private JPanel studentPanel;
    private JPanel enrolPanel;
    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JTextField nameTextField;
    private JLabel GenderLabel;
    private JTextField GenderTxtField;
    private JLabel raceLabel;
    private JComboBox raceCmbBox;
    private JComboBox genderCmbBox;
    private JLabel icLabel;
    private JTextField icTxtField;
    private JLabel religionLabel;
    private JTextField religionTxtField;
    private JLabel NationalityLabel;
    private JTextField nationalityTxtField;
    private JLabel addressLabel;
    private JTextField addressTxtField;
    private JLabel emailLabel;
    private JTextField emailTxtField;
    private JLabel contactLabel;         
    private JTextField contactTxtField; 
    private JLabel maritalLabel;       
    private JComboBox maritalCmb;
    private JLabel postcodeLabel;
    private JTextField postcodeTxtField;
    private JLabel countryLabel;
    private JComboBox countryCmb;
    private JLabel acdmcLabel;
    private JTable tbl;
    private JLabel no1Label;
    private JTextField no1TxtField;
    private JLabel no2Label;
    private JTextField no2TxtField;
    private JLabel no3Label;
    private JTextField no3TxtField;
    private JLabel dataTableLabel;
    private JButton registerButton;
    private JButton editButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JButton gnrReportButton;
    private JButton logoutButton;
    
    
    
    public Dashboard(){
       setSize(2000,500);
       setTitle("Dashboard");
       
       //component here
       tp =new JTabbedPane();
              
       studentPanel = new JPanel();
       studentPanel.setLayout(null); //default layout is flow layout, set it to null so then easily to set the location of each component
       
       nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
       nameLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
       
       nameTextField = new JTextField(25);
       nameTextField.setBounds(100,20,165,25);
       
       icLabel = new JLabel("IC Number: ");
       icLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
       
       icTxtField = new JTextField(25);
       icTxtField.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
       
       GenderLabel = new JLabel("Gender: ");
       GenderLabel.setBounds(300,20,165,25);
       
       String[] genderList = {"","Male","Female","Other"};
       genderCmbBox = new JComboBox(genderList);
       genderCmbBox.setBounds(390,20,165,25);
       
       raceLabel = new JLabel("Race:");
       raceLabel.setBounds(300,50,80,25);
       
       String[] raceList = {"","Malay","Chinese","Indians"};
       raceCmbBox = new JComboBox(raceList);
       raceCmbBox.setBounds(390,50,165,25);
       
       religionLabel = new JLabel("Religion: ");
       religionLabel.setBounds(10,80,80,25);
       
       religionTxtField = new JTextField(15);
       religionTxtField.setBounds(100,80,165,25);
       
       NationalityLabel = new JLabel("Nationality: ");
       NationalityLabel.setBounds(300,80,80,25);
       
       nationalityTxtField = new JTextField(15);
       nationalityTxtField.setBounds(390,80,165,25);
       
       contactLabel = new JLabel("Contact:");
       contactLabel.setBounds(10,110,165,25);
       
       contactTxtField = new JTextField(15);
       contactTxtField.setBounds(100,110,165,25);
       
       maritalLabel = new JLabel("Marital");
       maritalLabel.setBounds(300,110,165,25);
       
       String []maritalStatus_List = {"","Single","Married"}; 
       maritalCmb = new JComboBox(maritalStatus_List);
       maritalCmb.setBounds(390,110,165,25);       
                   
       postcodeLabel = new JLabel("Postcode:");
       postcodeLabel.setBounds(10,140,165,25);
       
       postcodeTxtField = new JTextField(15);
       postcodeTxtField.setBounds(100,140,165,25);
       
       countryLabel = new JLabel("Country:");
       countryLabel.setBounds(300,140,165,25);
       
       String []countryList = {"","Sarawak","Sabah"};
       countryCmb = new JComboBox(countryList);
       countryCmb.setBounds(390,140,165,25);
       
       addressLabel = new JLabel("Address: ");
       addressLabel.setBounds(10,170,165,25);
       
       addressTxtField = new JTextField(30);
       addressTxtField.setBounds(100,170,455,25);
       
       emailLabel = new JLabel("Email:");
       emailLabel.setBounds(10,200,165,25);
       
       emailTxtField = new JTextField(30);
       emailTxtField.setBounds(100,200,455,25);
       
       acdmcLabel = new JLabel("Academic Qualification");
       acdmcLabel.setBounds(10,230,165,25);
       
       no1Label = new JLabel("1.");
       no1Label.setBounds(10,260,165,25);
       
       no1TxtField = new JTextField(15);
       no1TxtField.setBounds(40,260,520,25);
       
       no2Label = new JLabel("2.");
       no2Label.setBounds(10,290,165,25);
       
       no2TxtField = new JTextField(15);
       no2TxtField.setBounds(40,290,520,25);
       
       no3Label = new JLabel("3");
       no3Label.setBounds(10,320,165,25);
       
       no3TxtField = new JTextField(15);
       no3TxtField.setBounds(40,320,520,25);
       
       dataTableLabel = new JLabel("Record Table: ");
       dataTableLabel.setBounds(580,1,165,25);
       
       registerButton = new JButton("Register");
       registerButton.setBounds(600,360,165,25);
       registerButton.addActionListener(this);
       
       editButton = new JButton("Edit");
       editButton.setBounds(800,360,165,25);
       
       deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
       deleteButton.setBounds(1000,360,165,25);
       
       gnrReportButton = new JButton("Generate Report");
       gnrReportButton.setBounds(1200,360,165,25);
       
       logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
       logoutButton.setBounds(1400,360,165,25);
       logoutButton.addActionListener(this);       
       
       int size = AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.size();
       String[][]data = new String[size][12];
       for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
           Student std = AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.get(i);
           data[i][0] = std.getName();
           data[i][1]  = "" +  std.getIc();
           data[i][2]  = "" +  std.getRace();
           data[i][3]  = "" +  std.getGender();
           data[i][4]  = "" +  std.getReligion();
           data[i][5]  = "" +  std.getNationality();
           data[i][6]  = "" +  std.getContact();
           data[i][7]  = "" +  std.getMarital();
           data[i][8]  = "" +  std.getPostcode();
           data[i][9]  = "" +  std.getCountry();
           data[i][10] = "" +  std.getAddress();
           data[i][11] = "" +  std.getEmail();
           data[i][12] = "" +  std.getAcdmcq1();

       }     
       String[]columns = {"Name","Ic","Race","Gender","Religion","Nationality","Contact","Marital","Postcode","Country","Address","Email","Academic Qualification"};
       DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);
       tbl= new JTable(model);
       JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tbl);
       sp.setBounds(580,20,1335,325);
       
       studentPanel.add(nameLabel);
       studentPanel.add(nameTextField);
       studentPanel.add(icLabel);
       studentPanel.add(icTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(raceLabel);
       studentPanel.add(raceCmbBox);
       studentPanel.add(GenderLabel);
       studentPanel.add(genderCmbBox);
       studentPanel.add(religionLabel);
       studentPanel.add(religionTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(NationalityLabel);
       studentPanel.add(nationalityTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(contactLabel);
       studentPanel.add(contactTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(maritalLabel);
       studentPanel.add(maritalCmb);
       studentPanel.add(addressLabel);
       studentPanel.add(addressTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(postcodeLabel);
       studentPanel.add(postcodeTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(countryLabel);
       studentPanel.add(countryCmb);
       studentPanel.add(emailLabel);
       studentPanel.add(emailTxtField);
       studentPanel.add(acdmcLabel);
       studentPanel.add(no1Label);
       studentPanel.add(no1TxtField);
       studentPanel.add(no2Label);
       studentPanel.add(no2TxtField);
       studentPanel.add(no3Label);
       studentPanel.add(no3TxtField);
       studentPanel.add(dataTableLabel);
       studentPanel.add(sp);
       studentPanel.add(registerButton);
       studentPanel.add(editButton);
       studentPanel.add(deleteButton);
       studentPanel.add(gnrReportButton);
       studentPanel.add(logoutButton);
       
    
       
       enrolPanel = new JPanel();
       
       tp.add("Student",studentPanel);
       tp.add("Enrolment",enrolPanel);
       
       
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Panel is added to the JFrane's content panel
       getContentPane().add(tp);
        //Set this frame visible to be display
       setVisible(true);
   }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource()==logoutButton){
           setVisible(false);
           AcademicSystem.user = null;
           LoginWindow lg = new LoginWindow();
           lg.setVisible(true);
       }
       
       else if(e.getSource()==registerButton){
           String name = nameTextField.getText();
           String ic = icTxtField.getText();
           String race = raceCmbBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String gender = genderCmbBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String religion = religionTxtField.getText();
           String nationality = nationalityTxtField.getText();
           String contact = contactTxtField.getText();
           String marital = maritalCmb.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String address = addressTxtField.getText();
           String postcode = postcodeTxtField.getText();
           String country = countryCmb.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String email = emailTxtField.getText();
           String acdmc = no1TxtField.getText()+" ," + no2TxtField.getText()+" ,"+no3TxtField.getText();
           
           if(!name.equals("")&&!ic.equals("")&&!race.equals("")&&!gender.equals("")&&!religion.equals("")&&!nationality.equals("")&&!contact.equals("")&&!marital.equals("")&&!address.equals("")&&!postcode.equals("")&&!country.equals("")&&!email.equals("")&&!no1TxtField.equals("")&&!no2TxtField.equals("")&&!no3TxtField.equals("")){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Profile registered successfully");
               boolean found = false;
               for(int i=0; i<AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.size(); i++){
                   Student std = AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.get(i);
                   if(name.equals(std.getName())){
                       found = true;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if(!found){
                   Student std = new Student(name,Integer.parseInt(ic),race,gender,religion,nationality,Integer.parseInt(contact),marital,Integer.parseInt(postcode),country,address,email,acdmc);
                   AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.add(std);
                   DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)tbl.getModel();
                   model1.addRow(new Object[]{name,ic,race,gender,religion,nationality,contact,marital,postcode,country,address,email,acdmc});
                   
                }else{
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"This user is exists in the record");
                }
            }else if(e.getSource()==editButton){
                    try{
                       PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("StudentInfo.txt");
                       for(int i=0; i<AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.size(); i++){
                            Student stdnt = AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.get(i);
                            p.println(stdnt.getName());
                            p.println(stdnt.getIc());
                            p.println(stdnt.getRace());
                            p.println(stdnt.getGender());
                            p.println(stdnt.getReligion());
                            p.println(stdnt.getNationality());
                            p.println(stdnt.getContact());
                            p.println(stdnt.getMarital());
                            p.println(stdnt.getPostcode());
                            p.println(stdnt.getCountry());
                            p.println(stdnt.getAddress());
                            p.println(stdnt.getEmail());
                            p.println(stdnt.getAcdmcq1());
                            p.println();
                        }
                        p.close();
                    }catch(Exception er){
                
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12 ==> this means that you are trying to read the 13th element of an array that has 12 or less elements.

Comment: @Stultuske then how should I do right now? add a break ?

Comment: This error is only occur when I have data in the text file, when that textfile is empty, the program is error-free

Comment: @matt stop trying to access the 13th, can I put break to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays are 0 indexed that means they start at zero,and the largest index is the length **minus 1**.

If you declare an array, and try to access an element beyond the length you get the exact error you are getting.

```
String[] data = new String[12];
data[12] = "this is an error";
```

Make your array bigger.

```
String[] data = new String[13];
data[12] = "this is fine";
```

This might be confusing if you are used to 1 base indexes.

More specifically, in your code you declare an array.

```
String[][]data = new String[size][12];
```

Then you try to access that array in a for loop.

```
data[i][12] = "" +  std.getAcdmcq1();
```

Note,that this code will not get run if size is = 0 because of the for loop condition.